# Match regex and extract all instances in json on MacOS

Tags: regex, bash, macos, grep

So i have a script that returns a json response which contains a key Name and it contains a filename.

So I managed to get it working in GNU grep but now I need it running on macOS, without installing anything, and FBSD grep can't use Perl syntax. Any idea how to accomplish this?

The variable files contains the json-response.

this works in GNU grep:

```
files=($(echo $files | grep -oP '"Name":"\s*\K[^\s,]*(?=\s*",)'))
```

Returns file01.jpg, file02.jpg and so on and stores it in an array.

Sample of the json response, is formated here but is in one single line:

```
    {
    "value": [
        {
            "Name": "file01.jpg",
            "TimeCreated": "2021-05-12T12:46:10Z",
            "TimeLastModified": "2021-05-12T12:46:10Z",
            "Title": null
        },
        {
            "Name": "file02.jpg",
            "TimeCreated": "2021-05-12T12:46:10Z",
            "TimeLastModified": "2021-05-12T12:46:10Z",
            "Title": null
        }
    ]
  }
```

How it's presented in the files variable:

```
{"value":[{"Name":"file01.jpg","TimeCreated":"2021-05-12T12:46:10Z","TimeLastModified":"2021-05-12T12:46:10Z","Title":null},{"Name":"file02.jpg","TimeCreated":"2021-05-12T12:46:10Z","TimeLastModified":"2021-05-12T12:46:10Z","Title":null}]}
```

Comment: Why `grep` and not a proper JSON parser?

Comment: can't install jq or any other tool, need to use what's built in since this will remotely run on a lot of machines.

Comment: I would sooner copy the JSON to a machine that *can* have `jq` installed than try to operate on it using `grep`.

Comment: macOS comes with Python installed, and Python has a proper JSON parser in its standard library. Use that instead of `grep`.

Comment: To be clear: grep is not the right tool to parse JSON because of all the edge cases that may crop up down the road. You may think you got your grep solution working, but somewhere in the future, you'll get some JSON that is not what you expect, and your program will fail, probably silently.

Comment: Right, would prefer to use jq or other tool but think this will work for this project.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A tool like `jq` is always better for parsing JSON but if you are unable to install it (as stated in question) then consider this `grep + awk`:

```sh
grep -oE '"Name":\s*"[^\s,"]*' file.json | awk -F '"' '{print $NF}'

file01.jpg
file02.jpg
```

Comment: Thanks, it's a single line without spaces, updated my question, how would it be then?

Comment: Brilliant, works on a computer with macOS so should be able to continue with this. Thanks!

Comment: before posting a duplicate of this question, now I have values that contains spaces, how to deal with it using the solution above? example "file - 01.jpg"

Answer (score 5):

In case you have GNU `awk` with you, please try following solution then.

```
awk -v RS='"Name": "[^"]*' 'RT{gsub(/.*"/,"",RT);print RT}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Simple explanation would be, using GNU `awk`, setting RS(record separator) as `"Name": "` till next occurrence of `"`. Then in main program if RT is not null then substitute everything till `"` in it and print it, which will be required values by OP.

Comment: Congrats for reaching 100k reputations!